# Bloodhound identify bug?

Tags: typeahead.js, twitter-typeahead

I'm using latest version of typeahead.js (v0.11.1). I observed strange behaviors when using different ids for dataset values.

I've created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3j80h5jL/). Here's the js code:

```
var ds = new Bloodhound({
    datumTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.obj.whitespace('name'),
    queryTokenizer: Bloodhound.tokenizers.whitespace,
    local: [{id: 1, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 3, name: "a"}],
    identify: function(obj) { return obj.id; }
});

$('#go').typeahead(null, {
    name: 'ds',
    display: 'name',
    source: ds
});
```

Now typeahead may malfunction if I change the data for 'local'. Here are just some examples:

Using one of these values for 'local' (notice the third element are random numbers starting with '1'):

[{id: 1, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 15, name: "a"}]

[{id: 1, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 1849, name: "a"}]

Now when I enter into text box: "a b", typeahead is expected to suggest "a b 1" and "a b 2", but in fact it only suggests "a b 1".

This can be fixed by one of these:

- Change 'id' property of third element to a value that doesn't start with '1'. Example:

  [{id: 1, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 23, name: "a"}]
- Change 'name' property of third element to a value that doesn't start with 'a'. Example:

  [{id: 1, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 15, name: "s"}]
- Remove 'identify' property of Bloodhound constructor object.

What's more, if I use a number greater than 2 as id of first element, like this:

[{id: 3, name: "a b 1"}, {id: 2, name: "a b 2"}, {id: 15, name: "a"}]

Now when I enter "a b" into text box, there's no suggestion!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answering my own question. Yes there is a bug in bloodhound. SearchIndex.getIntersection() function is incorrectly implemented. You can take out this function and test it like this:

```
getIntersection([1,2,15],[1,2])
```

It is supposed to return [1,2] as result, but in fact it returns [1]. This is because it uses sort() function incorrectly to sort numbers. According to w3schools:

> By default, the sort() method sorts the values as strings in
>   alphabetical and ascending order.
>
> This works well for strings ("Apple" comes before "Banana"). However,
>   if numbers are sorted as strings, "25" is bigger than "100", because
>   "2" is bigger than "1".

So this function can be fixed by changing these two lines:

```
        arrayA = arrayA.sort();
        arrayB = arrayB.sort();
```

into:

```
        arrayA = arrayA.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
        arrayB = arrayB.sort(function(a, b){return a-b});
```

Took me 1 day to find out :(

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Here is another way, we can just cast the id value to string `return obj.id.toString();`.